# How to make Rubymine working with minitest framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rubymine, minitest

Can't configure Rubymine to work with minitest normally. All the time it throws me exceptions

> Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly

Also, I can't run test by one (only all test running working), because in that case context do not load and all my classes goes to be undetermined constants (`NameError: uninitialized constant <MyVariableType>`).

I'm currently working with RubyMine 5 via Windows 7. (Ruby 1.9.3).

If someone know how to configure it properly i'll be very appreciate for your help.

Comment: Did you already read [this help section](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/minitest.html)?

Comment: Yes, I already read it. But looks like it do not help me at all.

Comment: It will help if you provide a test project that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I'm delete all previous gems and trying configure it step-by-step according the article you provide. And It solve my problem for a 50%. Now when I running all the test it works (ta-da!!!), but when I trying to run single test it fails with the reason described above (NameError: uninitialized constant for my variable type). Possible I'm doing something wrong and the are no Rubymine fault in it. My suggestion is when I'm trying to load single test it's not checking testcase.rb file and not load project context. Maybe i need to add some additional 'require' options to load tests that way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, great! I finally solve all my problems and now my rubymine working with minitest.

The short instruction:

1. Read [this manual](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/minitest.html) and do all the stuff step by step very careful
2. If it helps then say 'Yohuu!!!' and dancing victorious jig, if it
       still not working correctly goes to step 3
3. Add 'test-unit' gem to your gem file and update it with bundler.
4. When creating test do not forget to add `require 'test_helper'` add
   the top of the file.

**IMPORTANT: your test method names should start with 'test_' pattern, like test_my_supercool_method**

**UPD 1**: If you use Ruby 2.0, you ***don't need*** to use win32Console gem on Windows platform, even if jetbrains doc say that you should.

Comment: +1 this worked for me too, even though the error I was getting was different: `('method_missing': undefined method 'format_backtrace' for #<MiniTest::Reporters::RubyMineReporter:.....> (NoMethodError))`

Comment: Do you know how to get this to work with ruby 2.0?  win32console (apparently required) chokes with [Error “cannot load such file — 2.0/Console_ext” running unit tests in RubyMine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905821/error-cannot-load-such-file-2-0-console-ext-running-unit-tests-in-rubymine).  The error seems to be ruby 2.0 from what I can tell.

Comment: Use RubyMine 5.4+ and see my answer in your question. You need to remove win32console gem.

Comment: Would this work with minitest spec? The describe blocks don't have class names with a suffix Test?

Answer (score 1):

If you are following this guide (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.1/minitest.html?origin=old_help), you ***don't*** need to include `minitest-reporters` in your Gemfile or have this:

```
require 'minitest/reporters'
MiniTest::Reporters.use!
```

in your test_helper.rb file if you are using MiniTest 5 or newer. I was following a tutorial that was a little outdated and ran into this issue. Be sure to delete your .idea directory and restart RubyMine and you should be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this with the undefined method 'format_backtrace' error, and was getting green passing when the tests were failing and crashing.

Read the notes closely, if you are running minitest > 5.0, you don't need the minitest-reporters gem.

If you include it, perhaps like I did following the instructions, then you get the errors, and errors are not reported- (in my case, anyways).  So back out and remove the require minitest/reporters from your tests, and the MiniTest::Reporters.use! line and things should be good to go.