# Error "cannot load such file -- 2.0/Console_ext" running unit tests in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, rubymine, minitest

I'm trying to get started running unit tests for a sample ruby on rails application however RubyMine is printing out the following error whenever I try and run unit tests

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I've also gotten the same error when running `bundle install` since I added `gem "win32console", '1.3.0'` to my Gemfile.  Here is the error in text form

```
      Exception message: cannot load such file -- 2.0/Console_ext
["D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console.rb:12:in `require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console.rb:12:in `rescue in <top (required)>'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:13:in `require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/win32console.rb:1:in `require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/win32console.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'", "D:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.4.0.pre.2/lib/bundler.rb:130:in `require'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'", "D:/Users/Justin/Projects/Rails/blog/test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'", "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:51:in `require'", "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:51:in `block in require_all_test_scripts'", "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:44:in `each'", "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:44:in `require_all_test_scripts'", "D:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1/rb/testing/runner/tunit_or_minitest_in_folder_runner.rb:134:in `<top (required)>'", "-e:1:in `load'", "-e:1:in `<main>'"]
```

What is the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You no need win32console when working with Ruby 2.0. Ruby 2.0 on windows supports ANSI escape sequences, support unicode character output correctly. So the win32console gem is unnecessary. Remove it.

Also win32Console is an old gem - think they don't support Ruby 2.0

Comment: Thanks, knowing that win32console is not required I managed to get this working by following the instructions [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/minitest.html) and ignoring anything to do with win32console

Comment: If you mean jetbrains instruction about installing unittest, then I think it need to inform their somehow about the mistake, because normally they do not rewrite instruction each time when new product released, using the old doc for it. And sometimes their instructions goes wrong because of it.

Comment: Seems like the instructions were updated, since I didn't find any note about win32console there.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply comment out the reference to win32console in my Gemfile.  Thank you for the previous answer that pinpointed this.

In this case, my error was: c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/win32console-1.3.2-x86-mingw32/lib/Win32/Console.rb:12:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.0/Console_ext (LoadError)

This allowed the test to run, as well as bundle installs.  Long term I will likely delete the reference.